# Can we place the UI5 code in SAP netweaver server

Tags: sapui5

I am new SAP world, as i know we can save the UI5 code in the GIT or any other VCS (like Subversion).

As ABAP code can we place the UI5 (java script) code in the Server itself? in netweaver server itself?

So that i dont want to have separate code repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for NWDS, maybe its too oversized for your requirement. You can directly deploy from Eclipse or Web IDE to your SAP Backend Server, therefore you Need ADT (ABAP Developper Tools). The result is a BSP Page in SE80, clean and simple (but: there is no versioning, it is only pushing to the backend). 
https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/

Comment: versioning is required :(

Comment: you can use GIT or whatever CVS you like !! most Enterprises have internal gits for Versionen, only the deployment (push to the System) is done once..

Answer (score 1):

When you develop UI5 interfaces I assume you use NWDS (SAP Netweaver Developer Studio) for that. In NWDS you

1. [set up DTR](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/b0/a6de3f68d48f15e10000000a155106/content.htm) (Design Time Repository) server
2. [download](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70ehp1/helpdata/en/c3/e3a43f4aa1330ee10000000a114084/content.htm) development configuration from DTR
3. develop new functionality in this configuration

In such configuration all your developments will be stored on DTR server. DTR is a standard component of Netweaver landscape, and this is a standard way of landscape organization for team development recommended by SAP. 
So you upload (check-in) your UI5 code not to Netweaver directly but to Netweaver component called DTR. Hence you don't need any additional versioning systems here and UI5 code is handled as any other code (Java, XML, JS) in Netweaver.

**UPDATE:**
If you use SAP Web IDE with ABAP stack it allows direct deploy to ABAP UI5 repository.

[image]

If you use another IDE for development you can use other options which are  described in note [1793771](http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1793771):

- SAPUI5 Team Repository Provider Eclipse plugin
- ABAP report `/UI5/UI5_REPOSITORY_LOAD`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But we do not have netweaver Java stack.  We have our Fiori launchpad and UI5 in ABAP webAS. Is there a way we develop and manage it directly on Netweaver ABAP WebAS ?

Comment: Do you use SAP Web IDE for development?

Comment: I've written [a .NET command line tool](https://github.com/kleferbe/ui5uploader) to upload a UI5 app to the BSP/MIME repository. It uses the /UI5/UI5_REPOSITORY_LOAD Report Suncatcher mentioned internally. You can than add a button to your prefered IDE to upload the app with one click.